# Работа PyAutoGUI на VPS

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud

При выполнении команды pyautogui.pixel(x, y) и сворачивании активного окна подключения к VPS, возникает ошибка:

> ```
> while pyautogui.pixel(160, 63) != (84, 195, 243):
> File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 467, in pixel
> raise WindowsError("windll.gdi32.GetPixel faild : return {}".format(color))
> OSError: windll.gdi32.GetPixel faild : return -1
> ```

Я посчитал, что ошибка появляется из-за отсутствия виртуального дисплея. Включил его и установил драйвера Google Graphics Array (GGA), однако это не помогло.
Как осуществить работу pyautogui на VPS сервере Windows от Google Cloud?
Если окно подключения не сворачивать, то код выполняется нормально.

UDP:
Проблема решается, если подключиться к VPS через другой VPS. Но есть ли другой способ решения без дополнительного подключения?